# MariaDB: Hide Warning "Duplicate entry" while commit "INSERT IGNORE"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 5.5.54.
I have to use many "**INSERT IGNORE**" commands to summarize my data.
While I commit "**INSERT IGNORE**" and row with same primary key (or, in some situations, a unique key for multiple columns) is existing,
"**Warning: ...... Duplicate entry ......**"
shows.
Above message may show for million times while my command-line program is executing.
How to hide this type of warning message? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** to hide the warnings like:

```
INSERT INTO `so` (id)
VALUES
    (6)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  id = VALUES(id);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `so` (id)
    -> VALUES
    ->     (6)
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  id = VALUES(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `so` (id) VALUES (6);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '6' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO `so` (id) VALUES (6);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO `so` (id) VALUES (6);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `so` (id) VALUES (6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  id = VALUES(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`, instead `INSERT IGNORE`, solve my issue exactly. Thanks!

Comment: To handle a unique key for multiple columns, we can refer these columns, separated by comma like `INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, val3, ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2=val2, col3=val3;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are "normalizing" millions of rows, and many are already in the table, then consider the following.  The following code runs a lot faster (since it batches) and avoids the warnings by not trying to insert rows that already exist.  It involves 2 queries, one to insert *new* rows, one to fetch *all* ids.

The details are [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) .

(Note:  It includes `IGNORE`, but only to facilitate multiple threads that might rarely insert the same `name` 'simultaneously'.)

Comment: This can avoid Warning by additional constraints while still using `IGNORE`; a litle more complicated way but run faster in some situations. Thanks!

Answer (score -8):

Primary key have to be unique. If you want allow duplicate data remove primary key for the column.

```
Alter table yourtable drop index `yourprimarykey`;
```

Comment: if there no **primary key** the rows are duplicated

Comment: @jesuisgenial - Any `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key is checked the same way.  If there is a dup, you get a warning and the row is not inserted.  Without such keys, you can't prevent inserting duplicates!